# How to compose several UIImageViews nicely in an UITableViewCell?

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiimageview

I have an UITable view which shows news feed. In each cell there could be no images at all, or 1-5 images. How can I make it work as shown on the screenshots? 
[image: screenshot 1: several images in the bottom of the cell]
[image: screenshot 2: one image in the bottom of the cell]

Comment: this is not a simple question. google about algorithms to create photo collages.